# What Apache modules do I need for a minimum install?

Tags: apache-http-server

This is a list of my Aache 2 modules. I want to serve up millions of small images (1-20 kb) with the smallest memory footprint.  What can I disable?

core_module, log_config_module, logio_module, mpm_prefork_module, http_module, so_module, alias_module, auth_basic_module, authn_file_module, authz_default_module, authz_groupfile_module, authz_host_module, authz_user_module, autoindex_module, cgi_module, deflate_module, dir_module, env_module, mime_module, negotiation_module, reqtimeout_module, setenvif_module, status_module

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a webpage which details [which Apache modules can be safely removed](http://haydenjames.io/strip-apache-improve-performance-memory-efficiency/). He considers **the most common use cases** but you should always **check afterwards and reenable what you do need**:

This is the list of modules that the author left enabled:

```
core_module (static)
log_config_module (static)
logio_module (static)
version_module (static)
mpm_event_module (static)
http_module (static)
so_module (static)
auth_basic_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
expires_module (shared)
deflate_module (shared)
headers_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
```

The page contains details for CentOS and also Ubuntu server. I highly recommend reading the entire page as it contains details as to why certain packages were left or were disabled, as well as tips.